# How can i change this vba code to just grab the auto filtered range and not the second row?

Tags: excel, vba

As i stated in the question i am having troubles copying and pasting just the auto filtered range. The code grabs the second row as well as the auto filtered range every time. any idea on how to fix this problem?

```
Sub Copy()
        Dim src As Worksheet
        Dim tgt As Worksheet
        Dim filterRange As Range
        Dim copyRange As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim DestLastRow As Long
    
    Set src = Workbooks("Shipping Test.xlsm").Worksheets("LOWES HD")
    Set tgt = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")

    ' turn off any autofilters that are already set
    src.AutoFilterMode = False
 
    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
    Set filterRange = src.Range("A2:S" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
    ' in this case we are copying country from column A
    ' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A2:S" & lastRow)

    ' filter range based on column J
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="DISPATCHED"

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    DestLastRow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
    
    'Turn off Auto Filter again
    src.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: is row#2 the header row?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent no the header is row #1, row #2 is the first row with data

Comment: Normally you set your filter on the header row, not the first row of data, then you can either use the `FilterRange` with `Offset` and `Resize` to set the copy range. But, by setting the `copyRange` to `Range("A2:S" & lastRow)`, you are telling it to contain `Row2`, you just need to replace the `2` with `3`.

Comment: @GMalc Thanks that worked!